# Why can't I edit this question?

Tags: discussion, editing

I came across [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/20579/why-is-the-usa-able-to-damage-russian-economy-by-putting-sanctions-but-russia-ca) and to my surprise the edit button was disabled.

[image]

But on [another question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/20553/erdogan-and-the-people-he-fired) from the same user, the edit button is enabled.

[image]

According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled):

> 1. A large number of suggested edits by you were rejected in the past week (at least [5 more than one-third of your accepted
>      edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days/92337#92337)).
> 2. We are out of empty slots in the queue (40, with several exceptions. See
>      [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84362/whats-the-fixed-size-of-the-suggested-edit-queue/84398#84398)
>      for details)
> 3. You have 5 suggested edits pending.
> 4. There is a suggested edit to the post you're trying to edit that was not approved yet.
> 5. You are not logged in and the post is less than 10 minutes old.
> 6. You are on a child meta.
> 7. A moderator has banned you from suggesting edits.
> 8. Your account is suspended.
> 9. The post is locked.

I have only a handful of edit suggestions, all of which were approved. All other points do not apply either except number 2, because that's something I don't know (That whether or not there are free slots on editing queue). But what makes me dubious about this is that I can click the edit button on any question, just not this one. I am not sure if this is a bug so I am tagging it as discussion instead.

And I just noticed that edit button is disabled on all Politics Meta questions as well. But it is enabled on all main Politics SE questions except the one I linked above.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the confusion has been cleared up ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, an anonymous user had submitted an edit request there which has now been [approved](https://politics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/13932).

I of course did not have the privilege to see pending edit which is why it was just disabled for me and did not show me the count wrt pending edits which is what I am accustomed to seeing in this sorta situation.

So it [was #4 which disabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled) the button for me:

> 4. There is a suggested edit to the post you're trying to edit that was not approved yet.